# Apache Spark Time based Kafka off set

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using spark consumer (from `spa‌​rk-streaming-kafka_2‌​.10` version **1.6.0**).

My spark launcher listen message from kafka queue with 5 partition.Suppose I stop my spark application then it will read either smallest or largest offset value based on what I configure. But I Spark application should read message after I stop.for example I stop process 3.00PM and start spark launcher at 3.30PM.Then i am want to read all message between 3.00pm to 3.30PM.

Comment: What version of spark streaming do you use (standard/structured)? If standard: do you use receiver based appoach or direct streaming?

Comment: <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>,<artifactId>spa‌​rk-streaming-kafka_2‌​.10</artifactId><ver‌​sion>1.6.0</version>‌​

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using the high level consumer from Kafka library. In that case they will keep periodically committing the offsets and Kafka itself maintains the offset records either in Zookeeper or in some Kafka topics. So, when you restart the consumers in the group after some time, they will start from where they left. The offset records function as marker for where a consumer should start consuming in case of restart or rebalance. The offset commit may happen automatically or may be committed explicitly. In either case, the message processing and offset commit don't happen atomically, so there is a chance that few messages will be processed again in case of restart of consumers.

The smallest and largest offset values are only relevant when we start the consumers in the consumer group for the first time, as there is no offset records available for the consumers to signal them from which offsets (of the partitions) they should start consuming.

Comment: I am using spark consumer(<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>,<artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId><version>1.6.0</version>) and if i will not give  any offset by default its "auto.offset.reset"="largest".I am not able to consume message between time period when stop process and start again .